# Finding for X in a Probability Equation

Tags: probability, statistics

I've come up with an equation for my job.  Currently it solves for z, the probability.  I need it to solve for X, given the probability.  This will be used in a computer program.  The equation is as such:

```
y^x * (1-y)^(1-x) / (1-x)! / x! = z
```

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Is there a bracket missing ? Is it $y^x \cdot (1-y)^{1-x} / \color{red}{[} (1-x)! / x! \color{red}{]}= z$ ?

Comment: Is $y$ a known function of $x$?  What is the nature of $x$...is it an integer?  is it positive or negative?  Are the factorials to be understood as values of the Gamma function?

Comment: x and y are both percentages.  Y will be a known input into the equation, but needs to remain a variable in the program.

Comment: Some observation: The LHS is proportional to the pdf of $\text{Beta}(x+1, 2-x)$, just missing the factor 2. (assume that interpretation is the same as lulu suggested, otherwise does not make sense anyway). There are possible two roots to the equation, esp when $y$ is near $0.5$; you may try to fix different values of $y$ and plot out the LHS as a function of $x$. And there should be no closed-form solution for this as expected, instead you may want a numerical algorithm to solve it.